# What do we know about Sorli's Conjecture and Odd Perfect Numbers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, open-problem, perfect-numbers

I have seen that Jose Arnaldo Dris has recently published a great deal of literature concerning odd perfect numbers and Sorli's Conjecture. He claims that the truth of Sorli's conjecture implies that there are no odd perfect numbers. However, he then has a paper in which he states that he has proven Sorli's conjecture. What exactly do we know or not know at this point regarding odd perfect numbers and Sorli's Conjecture? Thank you.

Comment: Hi @JasonBrighouse.  Thank you for expressing an interest in my papers on Sorli's / Descartes's conjecture on odd perfect numbers.  As it currently stands, there are several "holes" that need to be filled in order to complete the "proof".  That is all I can say, for now.